# Precondition V.S. throw in Swift

Tags: swift, throw

What's the difference between `Precondition` and `throw` in Swift ?

Consider this case:

```
func isRange(start: Int, end: Int, value: Bool) -> Bool {
    precondition(end > start, "Start greater than end")
    if end == start {
        return true
    }
    ...
}
```

V.S.

```
func isRange(start: Int, end: Int, value: Bool) throws -> Bool {
    if (end < start) {
        throw Error.IllegalArgumentException(reason: "Start greater than end")
    }
    if (end == start) {
        return true // empty range matches
    }
    ...
}
```

Which one do you prefer?

Comment: The major difference is that you *must* catch exceptions, but *can't* catch a precondition failure.

Comment: @zneak I've noticed that there is a comment in `precondition` definition saying: *Use this function to detect conditions that must prevent the program from proceeding even in shipping code.* What is the situation of using this ?

Comment: for one example, Swift's arrays use `precondition` to verify that you're not reading out of bounds.